# Status in Android

Tags: android, adb

During the test, the application stops responding. Is there a way to find out the status of the application via adb? I tried

`adb shell pidof app`,

the app is still running

Comment: What test are you talking about? What status do you expect? Apps usually can "run" without doing anything (waiting for user input).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `logcat` to see the messages or exceptions of the app before stopping.

Logcat is a command-line tool that dumps a log of system messages, including stack traces when the device throws an error and messages that you have written from your app with the Log class.

See more details at [Logcat command-line tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) .